# pthread_cancel always crashes

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

I have a program that is trying to use create and cancel through an implemented pool.

The creation is as follows:

```
while (created<threadsNum){
    pthread_t newThread;
    pthread_struct *st; //Open the thread that handle the deleting of the sessions timeout.
    st = (pthread_struct*)malloc(sizeof(pthread_struct));
    st->id = created;
    st->t = &newThread;
    pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex_threadsPool );
    readingThreadsPool[created] = st;
    pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex_threadsPool );
        if((threadRes1 = pthread_create( &newThread, NULL, pcapReadingThread, (void*)created)))
        {
        syslog(LOG_CRIT, "Creating Pcap-Reading Thread %d  failed.",created); 
                printf( "Creating Pcap-Reading Thread %d  failed.\n",created);
                exit(1);
        }
    syslog(LOG_INFO, "Created Pcap-Reading Thread %d Successfully.",created); 
    created++;
}
```

Later I try to cancel them and restart them :

```
pthread_t* t;
pthread_struct* tstr;
int i;
pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex_threadsPool );
//first go on array and kill all threads
for(i = 0; i<threadsNum ; i++ ){
    tstr = readingThreadsPool[i];
    if (tstr!=NULL){
        t = tstr->t;
                    //Reaches here :-)
        if (pthread_cancel(*t)!=0){
            perror("ERROR : Could not kill thread");
        }
        else{
            printf("Killed Thread %d \n",i);
        }
                    //doesnt reach here

    }
}
```

I checked the addresses in the memory of the created thread in part one and the address of the about to be cancelled thread in the second part..they match..
I read about the thread manager that can't work if one calls killall().

But I don't..

Anyone have any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Is this not C? I see nothing C++ specific in the posted code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while (created<threadsNum){
    pthread_t newThread;
    pthread_struct *st;
    /* ... */
    st->t = &newThread;
    /* ... */
}
```

You've got `st->t` pointing to a local variable `newThread`. `newThread` is only in scope during the current loop iteration. After this iteration `st->t` will contain an invalid address.

`newThread` is on the stack, so after it goes out of scope that stack space will be used for other variables. That could be different `pthread_t`s on successive iterations, or once the loop is over then that stack space will be used for completely different types of values.

To fix this I'd probably change `pthread_struct.t` to be a `pthread_t` instead of a `pthread_t *`, and then change the pthread_create call to:

```
pthread_create(&st->t, /*...*/)
```

Also, you should be careful about adding `st` to the thread pool before you've called `pthread_create`. It should probably be added after. As it stands, there's a small window where `st->t` is on the thread pool but has not been initialized.

Comment: @ John, I did just that..but now , after creating 10 threads successfully, the thread in the 0 index gets
"Could not kill thread: Illegal seek"
and threads 1-9 are cancelled successfully...Do you have any idea of why the first one didn't cancel?

Comment: By saying "did just that" I mean I changed the st-> to be a thread rather a pointer.